# Minimize length of paths needed to connect multiple destinations

Tags: algorithm, graph

In something like a ticket-to-ride scenario, given a graph, one must build a set of paths to connect different destinations together. This is in contrast to a problem which minimizes the total distance traveled (like the traveling salesman problem). However, this problem instead minimizes the *distance of the paths needed*, so that a solution might look something like lots of branching paths.

What algorithm could accomplish this?

Comment: Is this [Steiner tree in the graph setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Steiner_tree_in_graphs_and_variants)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the graph version of the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Steiner_tree_in_graphs_and_variants). Steiner tree is known to be NP-hard to approximate, but in practice that may not be such an obstacle. The easiest algorithm I can think of that will work decently in practice is to use an integer program solver as follows. Start with a program like

```
minimize sum_{e in edges} length(e) x(e)
subject
x(e) in {0, 1}
```

and then

1. Use a library to solve the current program to optimality.
2. Find the connected components of the subgraph comprised of edges `e` with `x(e) = 1`.
3. If all of the terminals belong to the same connected component, return that subgraph. Otherwise, for each connected component `S` that contains at least one terminal, add the following constraint. Go back to step 1.

   ```
   sum_{e in edges such that one endpoint is in S and the other isn't} x(e) ≥ 1
   ```